# R use packages installed through BiocManager in self packages

Tags: r, package, dependencies, r-package

I am creating an R package to plot some data from VCF files. I need to include `Biostrings` [package](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/Biostrings.html).

The problem is that if I specify `Biostrings` in my `DESCRIPTION` file:

```
#...
Imports:
  BiocManager (>= 1.30.19),
  tidyverse (>= 1.3.2),
  GenomicFeatures (>= 1.48.4),
  Biostrings (>= 2.64.1),
  ggbio (>= 1.44.1)
#...
```

It tells me it does not find it:

```
> devtools::install_github("cccnrc/plot-VCF")
Using github PAT from envvar GITHUB_TOKEN
Downloading GitHub repo cccnrc/plot-VCF@HEAD
Skipping 3 packages not available: ggbio, Biostrings, GenomicFeatures
✔  checking for file ‘/tmp/RtmpZkWQ8w/remotes2ee5f54e7e2a6/cccnrc-plot-VCF-d0a0d12/DESCRIPTION’ ...
─  preparing ‘plotVCF’:
✔  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
─  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
─  checking for empty or unneeded directories
─  building ‘plotVCF_0.0.0.9000.tar.gz’
   
Installing package into ‘/home/enrico/app/packrat-prove/plot-VCF-install/packrat/lib/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.2.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
ERROR: dependencies ‘GenomicFeatures’, ‘Biostrings’, ‘ggbio’ are not available for package ‘plotVCF’
```

On the other han, if I remove them from `DESCRIPTION`, the package does not work as it does not find the function:

```
#...
Error in loadNamespace(x) : there is no package called ‘Biostrings’
#...
```

How can I work this out? I tried to google and search here but no luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use BiocManager to install your github package:

```
BiocManager::install("cccnrc/plot-VCF")
```

Or use `BiocManager::repositories()` to tell `github_install()` about additional repositories. [devtools](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=devtools) delegates to the [remotes](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=remotes) package, so use remotes directly

```
remotes::install_github(
    "cccnrc/plot-VCF",
    repos = BiocManager::repositories()
)
```

Ask questions about Bioconductor on the [Bioconductor support site](https://support.bioconductor.org).

Comment: Thanks so much. Where shall I put biocmanager::repositories() exactly?

Comment: I updated the response with that information.